# How can I add an existing directory to a pnpm workspace while preserving its existing package locks?

Tags: pnpm, pnpm-workspace

Say I have a repository with `packages/foo/package.json` and `packages/foo/pnpm-lock.yaml`. I want to add `packages/foo` to a pnpm workspace at the repository root.

As far as I can tell, when I add `packages/foo` to `pnpm-workspace.yaml` and run `pnpm install`, pnpm ignores the existing `packages/foo/pnpm-lock.yaml` file and re-resolves the entire transitive dependency tree of `packages/foo/package.json` from scratch. It's important for the stability of this package that this *not* happen; many things break if this package's transitive dependencies receive an unlocked upgrade.

How can I get pnpm to preserve the versions from `packages/foo/pnpm-lock.yaml` when building the workspace's `pnpm-lock.yaml`?

Comment: Have you tried `pnpm add --preserve-file ../path/to/your/existing-package/package-lock.json`

Comment: `--preserve-file` isn't a real CLI option. Did you get that from ChatGPT or something?

Answer (score -1):

1. **Add Your Package to the Workspace:** Just manually add your package to the `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file. Something like this will do:

   ```yaml
   packages:
     - 'packages/*'
   ```
2. **Run `pnpm install`:** Do this from your workspace root. `pnpm` is pretty smart about workspaces and should respect your existing `pnpm-lock.yaml` in most cases.
3. **Check After Installation:** Once you run `pnpm install`, take a peek at your workspace's `pnpm-lock.yaml`. It should now include your package's dependencies, ideally matching what you had in your package's lock file.
4. **Handle Any Conflicts:** If things look off (like some versions didn't match), you might have to deal with version conflicts manually. This can happen if other packages in the workspace have conflicting dependency requirements.
   Remember, `pnpm` doesn't have a magic command to do this directly, but it usually handles workspace dependencies well.

Happy coding!

Comment: This doesn't work. As the original question states, pnpm does _not_ respect the existing `pnpm-lock.yaml`.